# Поддержка двух реализаций страницы в .net asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

Имеется проект на asp .net mvc Появилась необходимость расширить функциональность страницы (добавить несколько колонок в таблицу, изменить метод контроллера) для определенного клиента, при этом для других клиентов, страница и функционал должны остаться без изменений. Проект деплоится на сервере клиента. Какие образом лучше всего это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Контроллер - в отдельную библиотеку. Для специального клиента - деплоить специальную версию этой dll и специальный view.